# `Ord a =>` or `Num a =>`

Tags: list, function, haskell, types, type-signature

I have the following functions:

```
which (x:xs) = worker x xs
worker x [] = x
worker x (y:ys)
    | x > y      = worker y ys
    | otherwise  = worker x ys
```

and am wondering how I should define the types signatures of these above functions `which` and `worker`?

For Example, which of the following ways would be best as a **type signature** for worker?

`worker :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a`,

or

`worker :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> a`?

I'm just really confused and don't get which these three I should choose. I'd appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: What is your function actually *for*? Is it for numbers? Integers? Anything that can be ordered?

Comment: @Gabe The output is a number (i.e. `Float` or `Int`) hence the `>` sign above. Now I'm just not sure whether it should be `Ord a =>...` or `Num a =>...` 

Just really confused!!! Thanks for asking though, helped me eliminate the third one from the list :-)

Comment: @maclunian: You can use `>` on anything that has an order, not just numbers. That's why using `Ord` instead of `Num` works in the first place.

Comment: You just said "The output is a number", so you want `Num`. If the output could be a character or string, though, you'd want `Ord`.

Comment: @sepp2k , @Gabe , Thinking about it though, couldn't you just use `worker :: a -> [a] -> a`?

Comment: Just `Num` won't work, as not all numbers have an ordering, e.g. the complex numbers.

Comment: @maclunian: No. That would imply that `worker` could work with every type of list. However you can't use `>` on things which don't have an order, so you can't use a list of things that don't have an order with `worker`.

Comment: Out of interest, why aren't you using `minimum` from the Prelude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define the function without an explicit type signature, Haskell will infer the most general one. If you’re unsure, this is the easiest way to figure out how your definition will be read; you can then copy it into your source code. A common mistake is incorrectly typing a function and then getting a confusing type error somewhere else.

Anyway, you can get info on the `Num` class by typing `:i Num` into ghci, or by reading the documentation. The `Num` class gives you `+`, `*`, `-`, `negate`, `abs`, `signum`, `fromInteger`, as well as every function of `Eq` and `Show`. Notice that `<` and `>` aren’t there! Requiring values of `Num` and attempting to compare them will in fact produce a type error — not every kind of number can be compared.

So it should be `Ord a => ...`, as `Num a => ...` would produce a type error if you tried it.

Comment: Thinking about it though, couldn't you just use `worker :: a -> [a] -> a`?

Comment: You cannot. Since you have the expression `x > y`, it will complain, `No instance for (Ord a)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about what your functions do, you'll see that `which xs` returns the minimum value in `xs`. What can have a minimum value? A list of something `Ord`erable!

Answer (score 2):

Ask ghci and see what it says. I just copy-pasted your code as is into a file and loaded it into ghci. Then I used `:t` which is a special ghci command to determine the type of something.

```
ghci> :t which
which :: (Ord t) => [t] -> t
ghci> :t worker
worker :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> a
```

Haskell's type inference is pretty smart in most cases; learn to trust it. Other answers sufficiently cover why `Ord` should be used in this case; I just wanted to make sure ghci was clearly mentioned as a technique for determining the type of something.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Altered my answer after comments.**

It depends on what you want to being able to compare. If you want to being able to compare `Double`, `Float`, `Int`, `Integer` and `Char` then use `Ord`. If you only want to being able to compare `Int` then just use `Int`.

If you have another problem like this, just look at the instances of the type class to tell which types you want to be able to use in the function.

- [Ord documentation](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Ord_c.html)

Comment: Thinking about it though, couldn't you just use `worker :: a -> [a] -> a`?

Comment: Yes, you could. But you should use the power of type declaration as much as you can since the compiler will catch errors which are type related. Here's a good explanation why: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html#id598932

Comment: @augustss When you just downvote and say it won't work, no one is going to learn anything. So please tell us why it won't work so that I and someone else can learn from this mistake. I guess you are referring to that Num doesn't contain the compare functions specified in OPs question?

Comment: At least two people explained why `Num` doesn't work, hours before @augustss left his comment. Not to mention that it's immediately obvious if you look at the documentation for `Num` you yourself linked to (and by the way, those pages are outdated are really shouldn't be given as references anyway).

Comment: Even tough, it's much more helpful for everyone if you give a hint what the problem is and use a friendlier approach. It will take you maybe 10 seconds more when writing a comment, but it will benefit the community so much. Instead of having this mentality to prove people wrong all the time, why not just try to teach people in a more positive way? :)

Comment: @Ancide When I made my comment there were already explanations why `Num` won't work.  I thought you had posted your reply after those explanations were given.

Comment: I see! I was actually first to post :) Anyway, I learned something so it's fine. So thanks for pointing it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would always go with the Ord type constraint.  It is the most general, so it can be reused more often.

There is no advantage to using Num over Ord.

Int may have a small advantage as it is not polymorphic and would not require a dictionary lookup. I would stil use Ord and use the specialize pragma if I needed to for performance.

Comment: Thinking about it though, couldn't you just use `worker :: a -> [a] -> a`?

Comment: No, (>) is part of the Ord typeclass.  Without the constraint it is not defined